# Solving system using linalg with constraints

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, equation-solving

I want to solve some system in the form of matrices using `linalg`, but the resulting solutions should sum up to 1. For example, suppose there are 3 unknowns, x, y, z. After solving the system their values should sum up to 1, like .3, .5, .2. Can anyone please tell me how I can do that?

Currently, I am using something like `result = linalg.solve(A, B)`, where `A` and `B` are matrices. But this doesn't return solutions in the range `[0, 1]`.

Comment: Per the docs, `linalg.solve` is used to compute the "exact" solution, `x`, of
the well-determined, i.e., full rank, linear matrix equation `ax = b`. Being linear, there can be at most one solution. If the solution you found does not sum up to 1, then adding the extra constraint would yield no solution.

Comment: Thanks, I got it, but isn't there any alternative for linalg that can consider such a constraint?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Per the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html),

> `linalg.solve` is used to compute the "exact" solution, `x`, of the
>   well-determined, i.e., full rank, linear matrix equation `ax = b`.

Being
linear, there can be at most one solution. If the solution you found does not
sum up to 1, then adding the extra constraint would yield no solution.

However, you could use
[`scipy.optimize.minimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)
to find the point on the constraint plane which *minimizes* the quantity
`||Ax-b||^2`:

```
def f(x):
    y = np.dot(A, x) - b
    return np.dot(y, y)

cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: x.sum() - 1})
res = optimize.minimize(f, [0, 0, 0], method='SLSQP', constraints=cons, 
                        options={'disp': False})
```

---

For example, given this system of equations

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as LA
import scipy.optimize as optimize

A = np.array([[1, 3, 4], [5, 6, 9], [1, 2, 3]])
b = np.array([1, 2, 1])
x = LA.solve(A, b)
```

The solution does not add up to 1:

```
print(x)
# [-0.5 -1.5  1.5]
```

But you could try to minimize `f`:

```
def f(x):
    y = np.dot(A, x) - b
    return np.dot(y, y)
```

subject to the constraint `cons`:

```
cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: x.sum() - 1})
res = optimize.minimize(f, [0, 0, 0], method='SLSQP', constraints=cons, 
                        options={'disp': False})
xbest = res['x']
# array([ 0.30000717,  1.89998823, -1.1999954 ])
```

`xbest` sums to 1:

```
print(xbest.sum())
1
```

The difference  `A·xbest - b` is:

```
print(np.dot(A, xbest) - b)
# [ 0.19999026  0.10000663 -0.50000257]
```

and the sum of the squares of the difference, (also computable as `f(xbest)`) is :

```
print(res['fun'])
0.30000000014542572
```

No other value of x minimizes this quantity more while satisfying the constraint.

Comment: my A value is a list of tuples. Is it possible to explain how to apply the same approach but with a list of tuples? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative you could use [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) combined with the new row to your `A` matrix: `[1, 1, 1]` and `B` matrix `[1]`.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 0, 1],
              [0, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 0],
              [1, 1, 1]]
B = np.array([[0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 1.0]]).T
x, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(A, B)
```

This gives `x` as `[[0.3], [0.5], [0.2]]`.

Comment: is this adding the *free_variable* to the least-squares problem, I suppose ?

Answer (score 3):

You could add a row consisting of ones to A and add one to B. After that use 
result = linalg.lstsq(A, B)[0]

Or you can replace one of A's rows to row consisting of ones, also replace value in B to one in the same row. Then use 
result = linalg.solve(A, B)